# Keyboard Swap Keys - Mac Layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, 22.04, xkb

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed and I am using an Apple UK keyboard layout. Everything works fine except for the    `` ` ``/`~` key (directly right of the left `shift`), which is swapped with the `§`/`±` key (right underneath `esc`). Until a few days ago on 20.04, running `setxkbmap -option apple:badmap` worked perfectly fine to fix this. However, suddenly it doesn't, even before the update to 22.04. How can I fix it?

In case it matters, I use `kinto.sh` for an easy out-of-the-box mac keyboard layout - apart from this issue.

I have seen some similar questions around here, but I am confused and really not a Linux power user. Plus it is weird that it suddenly stopped working...

Comment: I can't tell why it stopped working already on 20.04, but as regards 22.04 please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Debian patch, which made the `apple:badmap` option possible, was unfortunately dropped a while ago.

I [objected](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/data/xkeyboard-config/-/commit/c95fcccce44a867434e1c2b814d95a796e7f4f65#note_305744) when I saw it. Maybe you want to help pointing out that the patch would still be useful in some cases.

Comment: thank you for your comment and for objecting! Unfortunately, I was not able to sign up to leave a comment but I will try again. Is there an alternative method now to fix it?

Comment: @CarolEisen: The patch isn't huge, and one way is to apply it manually, even if it's a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @CarolEisen: I linked to this Q/A from the commit document.